# $_POST não retornando de forma correta

Tags: php, html, html5

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Estou com um pequeno problema em um código de registro que estou estudando, quero fazer a ligação com ele no banco de dados, porém eu não estou conseguindo receber os dados via POST.

Segue o código e o erro:

http://prntscr.com/j6ip0s

http://prntscr.com/j6ip9y

http://prntscr.com/j6ipd7

```
                                <div class="card-body ">
              <form class="form-group" id="formInscrevase" method="post" action="registro_ml.php">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="now-ui-icons users_circle-08"></i>
                  </span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required="requiored">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="now-ui-icons text_caps-small"></i>
                  </span>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="requiored">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_email-85"></i>
                  </span>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="requiored">
                </div>
                <div class="form-check text-left">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                    Eu concordo
                    <a href="#something">com os termos e condições</a>.
                  </label>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer ">
              <a href="registro_ml.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-round btn-lg">Get Started</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Se puder postar o código, assim se os links saírem do ar sua pergunta pode ajudar outra pessoa

Comment: O problema é porque você criou o botão como um link que envia ate a outra pagina, você deve criar um botão submit e ele deve ficar dentro da tag "form"

Comment: Assim que você postar o seu código na pergunta, eu crio uma resposta com a alteração no código para você.

Comment: Faça um  tour pelo site https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Feito, editei e coloquei o código!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código esta desta forma, assim ao clicar no enviar ele simplesmente vai para outra pagina e enviar os campos via post:

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<a href="action_page.php">enviar</a>
```

E esta é a forma correta, colocando um botão submit dentro da tag form, assim ele envia todos os campos via post:

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Utilizando o código postado na pergunta:

```
<div class="card-body ">
    <form class="form-group" id="formInscrevase" method="post" action="registro_ml.php">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="now-ui-icons users_circle-08"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required="requiored">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="now-ui-icons text_caps-small"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="requiored">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_email-85"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="requiored">
        </div>
        <div class="form-check text-left">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
            <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
            Eu concordo
            <a href="#something">com os termos e condições</a>.
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-round btn-lg">Get Started</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Como sou novo, tentei entender seu comentário e realizar no meu código, o que eu errei? http://prntscr.com/j6j94v

Comment: O botão não deve ser um link( a tag 'a' ) e sim um input do tipo submit ou um button do tipo submit.

Comment: Editei a resposta colocando o seu código com um button do tipo submit.

Comment: Ah!! Entendi, muito obrigado manin!! :D